# Getting the right Checkbox Value in Array

Tags: arrays, laravel, checkbox, implode

I have a form where i collect data from checkboxes. 
Here is my form

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea name='description[]' placeholder="{{ Lang::get('core.description') }}" rows='6' id='description' class='form-control' required>
        {{ $day->description }}
    </textarea>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php $meal = explode(",", $day->meal); ?>
        <label class='checked checkbox-inline'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='meal[]' value ='B' class='' @if(in_array('B',$meal))checked @endif />
            {{ Lang::get('core.breakfast') }}
        </label> 
        <label class='checked checkbox-inline'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='meal[]' value ='L' class='' @if(in_array('L',$meal))checked @endif />
            {{ Lang::get('core.lunch') }}
        </label>
        <label class='checked checkbox-inline'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='meal[]' value ='D' class='' @if(in_array('D',$meal))checked @endif />
            {{ Lang::get('core.dinner') }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my controller

```
$day = $_POST['day'] ;

for($i=0; $i < count($day); $i++)
{
    $dataDays = array(
        'day'             => $_POST['day'][$i],
        'title'           => $_POST['title'][$i],
        'meal'            => implode(',', (array)$_POST['meal'] ),
        'description'     => $_POST['description'][$i],
        'cityID'          => $_POST['cityID'][$i],
        'tourID'          => $id
    );

    \DB::table('tour_detail')->insert($dataDays);
}
```

I get all the data right except meal. What am i missing with implode? I tried one without array as `implode(',', $_POST['meal'] )`, this didnt help. I tried `implode(',', $_POST['meal'][$i] )` but i got an error. Can you please tell me how can i get the right data from checkboxes.

thanks

Comment: Try do display Request $request object, there you will see all POST array

Comment: Keep in mind that for check boxes, *the value is only sent if the checkbox is checked*.

Comment: Yeah i know that. There are 3 checkboxes.. i never get more than 1 value even if i check more than 1. Always only 1 checkbox data comes

Comment: you need to use merge()

Comment: how can i do that?